# return a static const []

Tags: iphone, objective-c

So in my model I have the following code... I am successfully able to return each individual value. I want to know how am I able to return the entire speakerTable []... Maybe some advice. Thanks!

```
typedef struct {
    NSUInteger speakerID;
    NSString * speakerName;
    NSString * speakerPosition;
    NSString * speakerCompany;
} SpeakerEntry;

static const SpeakerEntry speakerTable [] = 
{
    {0, @"name", @"position", @"company"},
    {1, @"name", @"position", @"company"},
    {-1, nil, nil, nil}
};
```

This works correctly...

```
-(NSString *) stringSpeakerCompanyForId:(NSUInteger) identifier{
NSString * returnString = nil;
if ([self helpCount] > identifier) {
    returnString = speakerTable[identifier].speakerCompany;
}
return returnString;
```

}

This does not work at all..

```
-(id) getSpeaker{
//if ([speakerTable[0].speakerName isKindOfClass:[NSString class]])
//  NSLog(@"YES");
NSArray * myArray3 = [NSArray arrayWithArray:speakerTable];
return myArray3;
```

}

Comment: @Jennis Thanks, sorry never knew about that. Took care of it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`arrayWithArray` expects an NSArray, not a C array.

The first one works because you are using it like a C array.

Alternatively - don't use a struct, use an object instead:

Create a class called Speaker.

**In Speaker.h**

```
@interface Speaker : NSObject {}

@property (nonatomic, assign) NSUinteger id;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString name;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString position;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString company;

- (void)initWithId:(NSUInteger)anId name:(NSString *)aName position:(NSString *)aPosition company:(NSString *)aCompany;

@end
```

**in Speaker.m**

```
#import "Speaker.h"

@implementation Speaker

@synthesize id, name, position, company;

- (void)initWithId:(NSUInteger)anId name:(NSString *)aName position:(NSString *)aPosition company:(NSString *)aCompany {
    if (!([super init])) {
        return nil;
    }
    id = anId;
    NSString name = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:aName];
    NSString position = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:aPosition];
    NSString company = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:aCompany];

    return self;
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [name release];
    [position release];
    [company release];
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

And now in your calling code you can create an immutable array of speakers with:

```
Speaker *speaker0 = [[Speaker alloc] initWithId:0 name:@"name0" position:@"position0" company:@"company0"];
Speaker *speaker1 = [[Speaker alloc] initWithId:1 name:@"name1" position:@"position1" company:@"company1"];
Speaker *speakerNull = [[Speaker alloc] initWithId:-1 name:nil position:nil company:nil];

NSArray *speakerArray [[NSArray arrayWithObjects: speaker0, speaker1, speakerNull] retain]

[speaker0 release];
[speaker1 release];
[speakerNull release];
```

*note: this is typed straight in, so feel free to mention/correct typos or errors*

Comment: NSArray * myArray;
myArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:

Comment: The point is that although structs are used, Objects are preferred. There is overhead, but in practical programs, the benefits outweigh the overhead - it's easier to store objects, output them to plists, etc, etc. And, although I don't want to say too much about it, your struct won't compile if you use ARC on iOS5 or Lion, so you're better off learning how to do it properly in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

The method `arrayWithArray` takes in an `NSArray` as an argument, not a C array.